# Problem with Fluid-Sim

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to create a fluid simulation with Blender, in which a flood from a lake runs done a slope. I've built the simulation based on various youtube tutorials (I'm completely new to blender), and for some reason the sim just doesn't work. I've attached the blender file. I'd be very grateful if someone could take a look!

Cheers

https://we.tl/t-oevz36KIwJ

Comment: Please add screenshots of the problem. You’re more likely to get help that way.

Comment: “Just doesn’t work. here’s the blend file“ is requiring us to open the blend file, manage to have the same system set up as you, and look for what the problem is. What if you wanted the fluid to explode like an alien, but we think that’s an error?

Comment: Hi Joe. Welcome to StackOverflow. I had a look at your file, and you made a lot of beginner mistakes. I would recommend to watch some fluid tutorials and make some "easy" fluid tests with an easy setup to gather some experience with it. I just list some mistakes you made - not all. First, the domain should include all the area where the fluid will/should be. Second, all objects which somehow relate to the fluid should have applied their scale/rotation like effectors, domain etc. Third, the object which should "collide" with the fluid should have the type "effector"....

Comment: and please next time use https://blend-exchange.com/ to share your file, so other people can learn from your question